# Xamarin: import SKBitmap from local file (not Resource)

Tags: c#, xamarin, skiasharp

I am pretty new in Xamarin so I hope I am not asking something stupid.

I would like to import a local image as `SKBitmap` (SkiaSharp Bitmap).

If I try using the simple Decode method, like

`var skBitmap= SKBitmap.Decode("myImg.jpg");`

my skBitmap is null.

I can load the image using

```
var myImg = ImageSource.FromFile("myImg.jpg");
```

but how can I convert the `ImageSourse` to `SKBitmap`?

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter you put the Image File to external file path or put the Image to xamarin forms project like following screenshot. Both of them you need read the image by `standard .NET stream`
[image]

For example. I put the image like above path.

Here is my layout.xaml

```
  <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="hsvCanvasView" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200"/>
```

I want to set this Image to `SKCanvasView`. Here is background code

```
 public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
    {
        ItemsViewModel viewModel;

        public ItemsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            hsvCanvasView.PaintSurface += HsvCanvasView_PaintSurface;


        }

        private void HsvCanvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
        {

            SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
            SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
            SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

            canvas.Clear();
            string resourceID = "App23.faded_div.jpg";
            Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            SKBitmap bitmap;
            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceID))
            {

                 bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
            }
            canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap,200,200);
        }
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

Here is a helpful artcle, you can refer to it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/bitmaps

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the `✔` in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue